# Java LocalDateTime Duration fundamental

Tags: java, java-time, duration

Here's my code:

```
// check if the time within 10 mins
if (Duration.between(listOfAppointment.get(Integer.parseInt(indicator) - 1).getDateTimeOfAppointment(), LocalDateTime.now()).compareTo(Duration.ofMinutes(10)) < 0) { 

    try {

        listOfAppointment.get(Integer.parseInt(indicator) - 1).setCheckIn(true);
        System.out.println("The check-in has been done! Let's see your PT!");
        break;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again!");
        indicator = console.nextLine();
    }

} else {
    System.out.println("It seems that it's still too early, please wait util 10 minutes left!");
    break;
}
```

All related packages imported and I tried with sample date like one day after but still it always printed out the try-block content, please help me resolve it. Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code correctly and in a code block (i.e. enclosed in triple backticks). You should also print the exception stacktrace and include it in your question. Don't ever just ignore exceptions if you don't what or why is causing them.

Comment: Also, please make sure your code is a [mre].

Comment: If the appointment is in the future, shouldn’t you swap the arguments to `between()`? Like so: `Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), listOfAppointment.get(Integer.parseInt(indicator) - 1).getDateTimeOfAppointment())`? (You may also check your assumption that it’s in the future so you don’t happen to check someone in who should have been here yesterday.)

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Already updated my code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated answer - should swap the index of appointmentTime and now variables as below:

```
int index = Integer.parseInt(indicator) - 1;

LocalDateTime appointmentTime = listOfAppointment.get(index).getDateTimeOfAppointment();

LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

Duration timeDifference = Duration.between(now, appointmentTime);

if (timeDifference.compareTo(Duration.ofMinutes(10)) < 0) {

    listOfAppointment.get(index).setCheckIn(true);
    System.out.println("The check-in has been done! Let's see your PT!");
} 

else {
    
System.out.println("It seems that it's still too early, please wait until 10 minutes are left!");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're trying to check if the time of an appointment is within 10 minutes from the current time, and if so, set the check-in flag to `true`, isn't it?. However, there is an issue in your code. You are using a `try-catch` block unnecessarily and breaking the loop within the `try` block. Here is what I believe to be a corrected version of your code:

```
// Assuming you have already parsed the indicator as an integer
int index = Integer.parseInt(indicator) - 1;
LocalDateTime appointmentTime = listOfAppointment.get(index).getDateTimeOfAppointment();
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Duration timeDifference = Duration.between(appointmentTime, now);

if (timeDifference.compareTo(Duration.ofMinutes(10)) < 0) {
    listOfAppointment.get(index).setCheckIn(true);
    System.out.println("The check-in has been done! Let's see your PT!");
} else {
    System.out.println("It seems that it's still too early, please wait until 10 minutes are left!");
}
```